# Can I Tell mbunit that one of the row cases is expected to fail?

Tags: c#, testing, mbunit

I have a unit test, something like this:

```
[Test]
[Row(1)]
[Row(2)]
[Row(3)] //This value is expected to fail
public void Test_MyMethod(int value)
{
    Assert.IsTrue(MyMethod(value));
}
```

Okay, this is an extremely simple test, but, assume `MyMethod` returns False when value is 3. Is there a way to tell MbUnit that `Row(3)` will fail, and hence, pass the test. Of course, I want it to fail if the test doesn't fail.. makes sense?

I can just write out another method that tests for failure with `Assert.IsFalse` but just wondering if I can achieve the same thing in the same function.

thanks

Comment: You can pass the expected result as a second parameter.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot is there a documentation somewhere I can look up? Can't find anything on it

Comment: I'm not familiar with MbUnit's row/column oriented testing paradigm enough to know, but for NUnit style testing (which should work directly with xUnit, and possibly MbUnit as well), given your example code, I'd just use `TestCase` and add a second paramter: http://nunit.org/index.php?p=testCase&r=2.5

Comment: @PrestonGuillot Can you add your comment as an answer? I finally ended up doing an `expectedResult` param to go with the main parameter and it worked well enough. If you make that an answer, I'll be happy to accept it! thanks.